# Merging Models or result of multiple selected Lists

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, model

I have two models like:

```
class Users
{
    public string UName {get;set;}
    public int UType_id {get;set;}
}


class User_types
{
    public int UType_id {get;set;}
    public string UType_name {get;set;}
}
```

And I have another method for selecting data from db which returns List of data like:

```
public List<T> getUsers()
{
    string _query = "select * from Users";
    ...
    ...
    return result;

}

public List<T> getUserTypes()
{
    string _query = "select * from User_types";
    ...
    ...
    return result;

}
```

I want result for display in dataGrid Merged result of that tables like SQL code below:

```
SELECT Users.UName, User_types.UType_name FROM Users
LEFT OUTER JOIN User_types ON Users.UType_id = User_types.UType_id
```

Is there any way for do that when I work with WPF and MVVM pattern and I have so many Models and ViewModels.

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework or some other ORM? Then this could easily be solved with navigation properties.

Comment: Now I'm using dapper ORM but I think about EF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use Linq to join the tables and retrieve the data which can be displayed in your grid present in the view as shown below, if you are using entity Framework

```
var output= (from u in dataContext.Users
             join ut in dataContext.User_types on u.UType_id equals ut.UType_id
             select new { 
             u.UName,
             ut.UType_name,
             }).ToList();
```